# Convergence Point in Intersection of Family of Sets.

Tags: general-topology

$x_k \rightarrow x$ be a convergent sequence in a metric space. Let $\Bbb A$  a family of closed sets with the property that for each $A \in \Bbb A$ there's an N such that $k\ge N$ implies $x_k \in A$. Prove that $x \in \cap\Bbb A$

I'd like to prove above statement. What is the meaning of $x_k \in A$? Does it mean that we can make up convergent $x_k$ sequence with a member of A?

Answer (score 0):

It means all members of the convergent sequence are eventually in any set $A$. Now, what is the definition of closed that you use? If you are using a sequential definition that a closed set means it contains all the limit points, then you should already see the solution.

Instead, if you are using closed sets as a complement of open sets, you would have to prove that x should belong to all the sets $A$. For this, I would suggest a proof by contradiction.

Comment: What is the sequential definition of closed set? I only know the second one with open set.

Comment: and $x_k$ denotes only a certain term of sequence or total sequence itself? I started to feel confusing when I had started to deal with the sequence beyond one-dimension.

Comment: Sequential definition: A closed set contains the limit points of all sequences contained in it. $x_k$ means the kth element of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have $x_n \to x$.
Let $A \in \mathbb{A}$. We have $N$ such that $ k \ge N$ implies $x_k \in A$.
So the tail subsequence of $(x_n)$: $x_N, x_{N+1}, \ldots$ lies completely in $A$
and also converges to $x$. As $A$ is closed, this means that $x \in A$ (closed implies that if all members of a convergent sequence lie in it, so does its limit).

So for every $A \in \mathbb{A}$, $x \in A$, which is saying that $x \in \cap \mathbb{A}$, as required.